# How to start c app from desktop with double-click?

Tags: c

I have written one very simple app in C. I know how to run it through Visual studio, but i want to start it from desktop with a double-click. If I double-click on a .exe file made in folder, it does not start. How can I do this?

Comment: "very simple app in C" ... means, basically, it's a console driven app. Maybe include some `fgets()` to make your app *stop* for input and let you see the console window that (probably) was created and destroyed too fast for you to see (`char buf[100]; printf("Press ENTER\n"); fgets(buf, 100, stdin);`). Or make it create a file ... `FILE *f = fopen("C:\\itsworking.txt", "w"); if (f) fclose(f); else perror("oops");` then check for the file.

Comment: While the source code that generated the executable may have been C, the executable is just that, and executable - not a "C app" - there is no such thing.  I am pretty sure that it probably does start, runs to completion then terminates; probably faster the the GUI can render a window.  If your code is not interactive and does not accept user input before completion, it will not hang around.  Like any application that terminates, its window will close.  That is not at all C question; that is a how to operate a computer question, so off topic.

Comment: The guesses made in answers here (f/e, that the program is in fact starting and then exiting) are just _guesses_, and many of them Windows-specific. The OP needs to include enough information _in the question_ to substantiate such guesses for the question to be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to modify your code so that it will wait for user input before closing (and there are many reasons that might be inappropriate), you could create a batch file wrapper:

*myprog.bat*

---

```
myprog.exe
pause
```

---

Then either you can double click the batch file or create a shortcut to the batch file then edit the shortcut to set the path to the batch file and the path from which to run (so it can find the exe).

That pretty much emulates how Visual Studio runs your code without terminating the window.

Another method you might consider is a batch file such as:

*runner.bat*

---

```
%1
pause
```

---

Then you can drag-and-drop your executable onto the runner.bat icon to run it.  The advantage being that you don't have to create a new batch file and/or shortcut for every new executable.

Really though this is not a C question, or even a programming question - it is most likely off topic.  If your code is ever required to run to completion unattended in a batch file for example, you would not necessarily want to add any interactivity to the program itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that double clicking on a console app will open a new console window, run the program and then close the window.

VS studio does a trick where it runs the app in a new console window but keeps it open till you press a key.

You can add that same thing yourself - put a `getchar()` call at the end

Or you can make a bat file to run the app as per Cliffords answer

Answer (score -2):

1. 1st open the code with visual studio code
2. Run or Build the program
3. then u will find an executable file where u have saved your code
4. Open that executable file

but you must have installed mingw installed in your environment

Comment: What has MinGW to do with anything?  Perhaps you are thinking of Visual Studio Code - not the same thing as Visual Studio - the similarity is in the name only.  He has already mentioned that it build and runs.

Answer (score -3):

you must compile it first with mingw or like compiler. and start it with by code:
`cmd> yourdirectory(e.g Desktop)/ gcc yourcodefile.c` your question is available also internet => [how-to-compile-c-program](https://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-compile-c-program-in-command-prompt/)

Comment: Visual Studio != Visual Studio Code if that is what you are thinking. He has clearly already successfully built the executable. Besides this does not answer the question either. He is not asking how to compile it from the command line.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say.  The question is about running an existing executable, not building the executable - he has clearly already done that.  It is not a C or software development question, it is a "how does Windows work" question.  The point is if you double-click the file icon it _will_ run; the problem is that it is running and terminating instantaneously.  It is not normal for the window of a terminated process to persist.

Comment: As explained in my answer there are many reasons why you might not want to do that.  Often run to completion and terminate is exactly what you want the code to do normally (running in a batch or shell script for example).